# write_dynamic_frame.from_options generates multiple part fles

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to AWS glue world. I am trying to write write an **avro** file to S3. Data gets written to S3 folder, but, it's not what I want, instead it writes multiple part files like this:

```
run-1637354712957-part-r-00000
run-1637354712957-part-r-00001
run-1637354712957-part-r-00002
run-1637354712957-part-r-00003
run-1637354712957-part-r-00004
run-1637354712957-part-r-00005
run-1637354712957-part-r-00006
run-1637354712957-part-r-00007
run-1637354712957-part-r-00008
```

Here's the code:

```
def write_to_s3(data_frame, s3_path, file_name, glue_context):
    connection_options = {'path': f's3://{s3_path}'}

    glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(data_frame, glue_context, file_name),
        connection_type='s3',
        connection_options=connection_options,
        format='avro'
    )
```

Data frame passed to **write_to_s3** method is **<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Spark is running the code by using multiple workers. If you want to generate a simple file, you must use `coalesce` function or define chunks of data for define number of workers.